# How to list all users with specific role in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT-ID]` lists all users with their roles for specific project. There are different filters and formatters available but I can't seem to find the right way to just filter only by specific role.

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT

bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:12345678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - user:alice@foobar.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - user:you@yourdomain.com
  - user:someoneelse@yourdomain.com
  role: roles/owner
etag: ARBITRARY_ETAG_HERE
version: 1
```

What's the `--filter=` expression that I need to use to list only users with the role `roles/owner`?

Comment: I have a similar [question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/14210/how-to-filter-all-roles-with-specific-user-in-gcp) but I want to filter by member-name. The `--query` thing does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be achieved using another `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies --query policy:"roles/owner" --project $your_project_id --flatten="results[].policy[]" --format="csv(bindings.members[0])"
```

Comment: Yet another awkward and annoying inconsistency in gcloud. Docs link for reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/asset/search-all-iam-policies

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this requirement recently as well. You can achieve this without the use of the `assets` API.

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT --flatten="bindings[].members" --filter="bindings.role:roles/owner" --format='table(bindings.members)'
```