# How to filter all roles with specific user in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT-ID]` lists all users with their roles for specific project.

There are different [filters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) and formatters available but I can't seem to find the right way to just filter only by specific user.

> **HINT**: I reused the example code of [DevOps - How to list all users with specific role in GCP](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11291/how-to-list-all-users-with-specific-role-in-gcp)

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT

bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:12345678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - user:alice@foobar.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:12345678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/pubsub.serviceAgent
- members:
  - user:you@yourdomain.com
  - user:someoneelse@yourdomain.com
  role: roles/owner
etag: ARBITRARY_ETAG_HERE
version: 1
```

What's the `--filter=` expression that I need to use to list only items with the **members** `- serviceAccount:12345678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more googling, I found that [post](https://jamiekt.wordpress.com/2019/06/13/use-gcloud-to-list-all-project-roles-that-a-service-account-is-a-member-of/).

Sorry!

Here is the solution which works for me

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:serviceAccount:12345678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
```